# Signing certificate not showing?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, applescript, signing

I have a problem with signing on xcode there is no signing certificate on Signing & Capabilities:

[image]

Even though I have selected the certificate on Build Settings:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to login into apple id developer account with worked apple store connect and for the best use latest xcode version! Let Xcode autosign.